# Weird CentOS permission errors [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan/ (no solution works)

Tags: centos, azure-devops, devops, chmod, chown

> First let me start off by saying this exact installation works on
>   another VM of CentOS and Ubuntu without Issue. But i am having issues
>   with this specific install on the another CentOS VM.

I set my storage folder as /var/lib/ckan for my application.

Everytime i try to upload a file through resource create i get this error

```
[Thu Nov 08 23:59:50.286522 2018] [:error] [pid 23021] [remote 10.172.24.4:76] Error - <type 'exceptions.OSError'>: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/ckan/resources/ecf'
```

Now i tried everything.

I ran all of these commands and nothing has helped.

My httpd runs on the user apache.

```
sudo chown -R apache /var/lib/ckan
sudo chmod -R u+rwx /var/lib/ckan
sudo chmod 777 -R /var/lib/ckan
```

But nothing works. Do I have some funky permissions issue going on here??

```
[user@ckanserverckan]$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 8 23:45 resources
drwxr-xr-x. 2 apache apache 4096 Nov 8 23:57 storage
```

I suspect my installation of CentOS is having some weird permission issues here.

Its the same exact setup/commands i ran on another two VMs (centos, ubuntu) and i did not have this issue, so we can erase any python code issue.

This copy is on Azure(Running Centos 7.5)

Comment: Found the solution: SELinux is enabled on CentOS. That blocks apache from writing to non-default folders. Use 'sestatus' to see if it's enabled.
More info here https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

Comment: Disabling SELinux worked perfectly for me :)